# BIOS is not ACPI compliant Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) error while installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, installation, bios, bsod

I have an [HP 15-db1000AU](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06263818) notebook

Processor is 64 bit AMD Ryzen 3 2.6 GHz

It has 1 TB 5600 rpm HDD installed with Windows 10 Pro

I recently updated the BIOS from windows 10 and the BIOS screen shows the current revision number as F.13

I would like to install Windows 7 on this computer

I created a bootable USB using Rufus 3.8 (latest version) from a Windows Ultimate 64-bit iso file

I selected MBR and BIOS (formatted NTFS, this is the only option available) for booting options when creating this bootable USB (if I select GPT and UEFI it does not boot)

If I boot the notebook using this USB, I initially get the Windows is loading files progress bar, but then when the Windows animated logo screen comes out, the logo animation freezes and I get a BSOD that says the BIOS is not ACPI compliant. Basically the installation process does not proceed beyond this.

The BIOS has an option called Legacy Support which is enabled. The description says that enabling this will load the compatibility module (abbreviated as CSM or something)  which is needed for Windows 7 and older OSes, while disabling this option will only allow booting in UEFI mode, and it further says that with this option enabled UEFI boot order has priority over legacy boot order. I am guessing that this should be kept at enabled.

The current hard drive inside this notebook has Windows 10 and is working (although slow) and I want to install Windows 7 on my spare hard drive (I will be physically swapping the hard drive to do this)

How do I overcome the BIOS is not ACPI compliant problem? I have already updated the BIOS as suggested in other posts about similar errors, but nothing is working. I have seen this post, https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/314830/stop-error-code-0x000000a5-error-when-you-are-installing-windows-xp
on how to fix a similar error for Windows XP. What is the Windows 7 equivalent of this process?

Pressing F7 while the Windows is loading progress bar appears takes me to another boot option screen which has options like safe mode, safe mode with command prompt, etc. Non of hte options here work either, I always get the BSOD when I reach the Windows logo animation screen

**How do I bypass the BIOS is not ACPI compliant BSOD screen?**

EDIT ---

Is this a hardware issue with the motherboard or is this a BIOS issue? I c\have recently found out that the BIOS name is Insyde with version number F.13 - AMD AGESA PicassoPI-FP5 1.0.0.6

I found an old HP forum post here: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Update-BIOS-F-13-Insyde/td-p/5027757
which talks about updating Insyde F.13 BIOS version to something higher, but for a different model computer. This was from 2015 and I recently updated the BIOS in my computer a few days ago, but my BIOS version still says F.13. Is my BIOS different from the BIOS mentioned in the HP forum post? Is it possible to update my BIOS using the installer given in that forum post?

Comment: I assume your computer is simply too new for Windows 7, or your Windows 7 DVD is too old. Make sure you are using one with at least integrated SP2 but if that does not work you have to use Windows 8 or 10. See also https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/83l53s/raven_ridge_windows_7_psa/

Comment: @Robert win 10 is slow on this computer. Should i expect win 8 to be equally slow or could it be faster on these specs?

Comment: Every OS is slow on this PC because you use an 5600 rpm HDD. Use an SSD instead and any Windows version will run like hell.

Comment: New computers cannot run Windows 7 almost all of the time. I assume your spec means 5400-rpm drive. Those things are too slow for any operating system. Windows 7 will be slow as well.

Comment: No such thing as SP2 for Windows 7.

Comment: @Moab may be he meant this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-obtain-and-install-windows-7-sp2/c2c7009f-3a10-4199-9c89-48e1e883051e

Comment: my older computer had lower processor specs than this and windows 7 worked fairly fast enough on the 5200 rpm drive, so I just want to test out how windows 7 would do on this one

Comment: @user13267 that is a convenience rollup and was never released as a an official service pack. That is just what the Mod is calling it.